# ArgumentNullException with RhinoMocks 3.6

Tags: c#, rhino-mocks

Benn trying to test a service layer method which returns a simple IList using RhinoMocks 3.6

```
[TestMethod]
    public void GetItems_Returns_ActionItemsList()
    {
        // arrange
        var mockRepository = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IActionItemRepository>();
        mockRepository.Stub(s => s.Select()).Return(GetFakeActionItems());

        var service = new ActionItemQueueService(mockRepository);

        // act
        var actual = service.GetItems();

        mockRepository.VerifyAllExpectations();

        // assert
        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(actual, typeof(IList<ActionItem>));
    }
```

Real simplle right? 
The GetFakeActionItems method for reference;

```
internal IQueryable<ActionItem> GetFakeActionItems()
    {
        return new List<ActionItem> {            
                                        new ActionItem{
                                            Id = 5,
                                            ClientName = "Bank of American Corporation",
                                            ActionNeeded = RequiredAction.Change,
                                            RecordIndicator = "ROI",
                                            RequestDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3)
                                        } 
        } as IQueryable<ActionItem>;
    }
```

Here is the class and method under test...

```
public class ActionItemQueueService : IActionQueueService
{
    private readonly IActionItemRepository _actionItemRepository;

    public ActionItemQueueService(IActionItemRepository actionItemRepository)
    {
        _actionItemRepository = actionItemRepository;
        if (_actionItemRepository == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("ActionItemRepository");
        }
    }




    public IList<Model.ActionItem> GetItems()
    {
        return _actionItemRepository.Select().ToList<Model.ActionItem>();
    }
}
```

Nothing wild....
When I run my test, I Get an ArgumentNullException when the GetItems() method is called when _actionItemRepository.Select() fires. Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source.

Confused and perplexed wondering if anyone has any insight into what I am missing.

Many thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't you be doing something like
fakeItems = GetFakeActionItems();
... Stub(...).Return(fakeItems)?

Comment: technically? Sure. But it doesn't make a difference on the test method blowing up with the same ArgumentNullException. :(

Comment: Is there a reason why you pass a null in MockRepository.GenerateMock<IActionItemRepository>(null) ?

Comment: Was a stab it the issues I failed to remove before posting. With or without I besplode with same ArgumentNullException. Let me remove that from the post.

Comment: Maybe a stupid angle here, but can you show us GetFakeActionItems?

Comment: No problem Andrew, updated the post to include the GetFakeActionItems method as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you are taking your `List<ActionItem>` and performing "`as IQueryable<ActionItem>`" on it in your `GetFakeActionItems` method.  This returns null as it is not a valid conversion.

Thus, when your mock `ActionItemRepository` runs the stubbed out `Select()` it returns null (via `GetFakeActionItems`), which causes the subsequent `ToList<Model.ActionItem>()` to go down in flames with the `ArgumentNullException`.

What you actually want to do in your `GetFakeActionItems` is:

```
myList.AsQueryable()
```

Comment: Yep. That was the issue... Many thanks Adrew. Making the change allowed the test to pass as expected.